# React Sentry TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'componentStack')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I am trying to use the `ErrorBoundry` component of Sentry in my react project so that I can contain the errors reported to sentry just for my React app as it lives on many different websites and I don't want to pick up every JS error on every web page and website.

However, every error that is bubbling up from my react app into the `ErrorBoundry` produces a very obscure and uninformative error such as `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'componentStack')`

The actual error **without** the `ErrorBoundry` component should be `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

It seems like the `componentStack` is overriding and preventing any useful reporting as per these two images with the `ErrorBoundy` disabled and enabled respectively. These images are taken from my dev environment and I am the CRACO version.

**ErrorBoundry component added**
[image]

**ErrorBoundry component removed**
[image]

Code references.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Sentry.ErrorBoundary fallback={<ErrorFallback />}>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App shop={shop} customiserId={customiserId} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Sentry.ErrorBoundary>,
    customiser
  );
```

with a fallback component that looks like

```
const ErrorFallback = () => {
  return (
    <div>An error has occurred</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by upgrading from CRA 4 to 5. e.g. `react-scripts`. Maybe this helps someone else.